# Give different discounts for each product on Stripe Checkout

Tags: api, stripe-payments, product, discount

I'm trying to give **different discounts "20% Off" and "10% Off"** for **each product "T-shirt" and "Shoes"** respectively on **Stripe Checkout** but I could only find [**"discounts" parameter**](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-discounts) which will give **only one same discount** to all products:

[image]

Are there any ways to give different discounts for each product on **Stripe Checkout**?

Answer (score 0):

When creating a Checkout Session you can only set a maximum of one coupon. So it won't be possible to apply a 20% discount for one product and a 30% discount for another product.

One workaround could be to:

1. Compute on your end the total amount to discount, for example $20
2. Dynamically create a coupon for $20
3. Then pass that coupon when creating the Checkout Session